# No value passed for parameter 'info' in data class

Tags: kotlin

I have a data class

```
data class TaxEngineModel(
    @Id
    val Id: String = "",
    val environment: String = "",
    val tDescription: String = "",
    val EndPoint: String = "",
    val Type: String = "",
    val info: infoModel,
)
```

when I want to create an object, I got an error "No value passed for parameter 'info'", how to fix this issue?

```
val model = TaxEngineModel()
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but just wanted to point out the convention in Kotlin: Variable names should be camelCase (In your case, `Id`, `Endpoint` and `Type` should be `id`, `endpoint` and `type`), and type names should be TitleCase (in your case, `infoModel` should be `InfoModel`). I'd also consider renaming `tDescription` to just `description`, since `t` offers the consumer no additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error hints: You must pass a value for `info` or make `info` nullable. You have default values for all other backfields in your class, but not for `info`.

Pass a value:

```
val model = TaxEngineModel(info = someInfoModel)
```

or make info nullable:

```
...
    val Type: String = "",
    val info: infoModel?, // you could optionally assign null as default here
)
```

or define a default value:

```
...
    val Type: String = "",
    val info: infoModel = someInfoModel, // you could maybe create InfoModel here?
)
```

However in the later case, you'd need a global constant or something else the constructor has access to.

Comment: +1, although I would also add that for a nullable type you could pass `null` as its default parameter (`val info: InfoModel? = null`), and for a non-nullable type, provided that the type itself has default/optional parameters, you could just construct it (`val info: InfoModel = InfoModel()`)

Comment: Good points. I added the respective comments, to clarify. Thank you for the tip :)